# comparing times in 24h format in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with comparing two time values in format "hh:mm:ss". In my php script I'm running SQL query on my database and it's returning some stupid stuff like 19:19:00<19:01:03

```
SELECT * FROM temperature WHERE (datum>='$Datum' && vreme>'$Vreme')
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this--

```
//Pass the values as YYYY/MM/DD
function getdateDiff($dformat, $endDate, $beginDate)
{
     $date_parts1=explode($dformat, $beginDate);
     $date_parts2=explode($dformat, $endDate);

     // Provide (mm/dd/yyyy) in gregoriantojd function.
     $start_date = gregoriantojd($date_parts1[1], $date_parts1[2], $date_parts1[0]);
     $end_date = gregoriantojd($date_parts2[1], $date_parts2[2], $date_parts2[0]);
     return $end_date - $start_date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (put the query in single quotes `'`)

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temperature WHERE (datum >= '".$Datum."' AND vreme > '".$Vreme."')");
```

Comment: Just to be clear, in serbian datum means date and vreme means time. I'll now try your suggestion.

Comment: are you running this script in an php file? if yes can you paste your php code along with your question.

Comment: mysql_connect(...);
mysql_select_db("temperature");

$Vreme = $_POST['Vreme'];
$Datum = $_POST['Datum'];
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temperature WHERE (`datum` >= '"$Datum"' AND `vreme` > '"$Vreme"');
    while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
            $output[]=$e;
     
    print(json_encode($output));
     
    mysql_close();

Comment: It still does the same. Says that 19:5:53 is after 19:53:48

Comment: try a static query with 19:53:48 and 19:05:53

Comment: `$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temperature WHERE (datum >= '19:05:53' AND vreme > '19:53:48');`